# Is there some difference between use Tokens or strings in compiler construction?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, lexical-analysis, javacc

I was trying to optimize a compiler in JavaCC but then came across something that I never found while working with compilers in the past because I was taught to use tokens for any terminal.

This compiler sometimes uses strings in regular expressions of syntactic analysis instead of tokens, for example:

```
<TK_IF> "(" log_expr ")" body
```

instead of:

```
<TK_IF> <TK_LPAREN> log_expr <TK_RPAREN> body
```

This is just an example, in other parts of the code are used strings in operators like (+, -, !=, ==, >, <).

What I want to know is if there is some difference between use tokens or strings in the compiler, mainly about performance that is my goal optimizing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd think this is a non-optimization completely--any parser generator you're using would have the same behavior and inline all of the terminals/compile the regexes from the grammar. What performance issue are you having that you need to search for micro-micro-micro optimizations like this?

Comment: regex is a simplified and mintured subset of bnf grammar, so it might just be notation.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort No it isn't. It is a completely different thing, with some extra features as well as some missing features that are in BNF. Regular expressions predate BNF historically.

Comment: I meant the subset used in tokenizers. Note that many of the more recent capturing features from e.g. PCRE don't predate BNF.

Comment: @ggorlen, this compiler I'm working had to deal with new features over time so it's sort of a patchwork. My goal is to refactor it aiming increase performance, readability, etc. Because of that I'm searching for best practices in compiler construction, but I can't find it on web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in [the FAQ](https://github.com/javacc/javacc/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-does-it-mean-to-put-a-regular-expression-within-a-bnf-production).

Say I have two definitions (or lexical productions in JavaCC terminology)

```
TOKEN : { <ID : (["a"-"z","A"-Z"])+ > 
      |   <BECOMES : ":=" >}
```

This defines a token kind named `ID`. It corresponds to infinitely many strings that might appear in the input file: `apple`, `pear`, `fruitBasket`.  It also defines a token kind `BECOMES` that can only appear as the string `:=`.

In your BNF productions, you need to refer to token kinds.  So a BNF production might be

```
void assignment() : {} { <ID> <BECOMES> expression() }
```

But ---[as explained in the FAQ](https://github.com/javacc/javacc/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-does-it-mean-to-put-a-regular-expression-within-a-bnf-production)--- since the `BECOMES` token kind can only refer to the string `:=` --- and is presumably the only such token kind, JavaCC lets you write this BNF production as

```
void assignment() : {} { <ID> ":=" expression() }
```

The two ways of writing the production are identical.

In your case, the strings "(" and ")" in nonterminal productions simply abbreviate `<TK_LPAREN>` and `<TK_RPAREN>`, respectively.

*This abbreviation can only be used in BNF productions*.

Answer (score 4):

It's been common, in the past, to implement lexers / tokenizers such that they return "small integer" values for each token-type-number:

```
IF the next token is the word "def" THEN RETURN 257 FI
```

for instance.  Combining this with the use of 7 or 8-bit character sets, we immediately see that all 256 possible character values are available as token values.  So "`(`" can just be token number 40 (see any ASCII table).

You can often tell whether someone's using this sort of notation because single-character operators like `+` will be encoded this way (`+` = 43), but a two-character operator like `+=` will have a named token.  Another giveaway occurs when code that generates token-finding code generates a token table, and the first *named* token's numeric value is just above 255, the maximum 8-bit value.

In the end, this isn't really very important: it's just an implementation quirk.  If you write your own scanner and parser, you'll do whatever is appropriate to return the appropriate token-code to your parser.  How you turn some input syntax into the appropriate *code* is up to you.